# Multiplication of Integer.MAX_VALUE in Java

Tags: java

I was just playing around in Java. Wrote this small program:

```
public class MaxValue{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i  =  Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int j = 1; j<=10;j++){
            System.out.println(i*j);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

> 2147483647
>
> -2
>
> 2147483645
>
> -4
>
> 2147483643
>
> -6
>
> 2147483641
>
> -8
>
> 2147483639
>
> -10

Now I got surprised. I do not know how to explain this output. I know I can use long instead for handling values more than the max limit of integer. However I am only interested to know how java calculates the this?

Comment: For you interest try `-1 * Integer.MIN_VALUE` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to analize binary content of the result:

Integer.MAX_VALUE * 1 = 0x7fffffff which is decimal 2147483647

Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2 = 0xfffffffe which is -2

Integer.MAX_VALUE * 3 = 0x17ffffffd but it is 33 bits, after truncation it is 0x7ffffffd which is 2147483645

and so on...

Answer (score 2):

It is called an overflow. Since you are operating over the maximum possible value, any mathematical increasing operation can potentially end up in an overflow.

More info about overflows in Java: http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-overflow-and-underflow/

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is called `overflow`, with primitive type java will handle this in the following way : - On reaching the `Integers.MAX_VALUE` it will just go to the `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and this way you just get a negative value